# How to JOIN these 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysqli

I have the following JOIN query already done:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT p.post_id, p.reply_to, p.parent_id, p.post_path, p.user_id, p.content, p.datetime, p.total_likes, p.total_replies, p.total_reposts, u.username, u.display_name FROM posts p LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id WHERE p.user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows WHERE user_id = ?) AND p.removed != 1 ORDER BY p.datetime DESC LIMIT 26');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_info[0]);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have another query that's only purpose is to check if a row exists or not:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(like_id) FROM likes WHERE post_id = ? AND user_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $row['post_id'], $user_info[0]); // $row['post_id'] is the value of p.post_id from the first query
$stmt->execute();
```

How would I join the second query into the first one? I've never joined 3 tables so I'm unsure of the procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: It's generally bad form to remove a question like this- can you use anonymized table names to allow future users to benefit from your question, also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining three tables in a query is like joining two, except... you join three.

Basically it would go something like this:

```
SELECT p.post_id (...), u.username (...), COUNT(l.like_id) AS nbOfLikes
    FROM posts p
    LEFT JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
    LEFT JOIN likes l ON l.post_id = p.post_id AND l.user_id = u.user_id
    WHERE p.user_id IN
        (SELECT following_id
            FROM follows
            WHERE user_id = ?)
    AND p.removed != 1
    ORDER BY p.datetime DESC
    LIMIT 26;
```

-- Actually I think a `UNION` would perhaps be more adapted to your need concerning the `likes` table.

Comment: What is the `AS likeNumber` part?

Comment: It's to give a name to your `count(l.like_id)` part. So in your PHP code you will refer to it as `likeNumber` (and also, if you need it, further in your SQL request, which is more convenient). But it's optional.

Comment: @user3268045 but I agree it's not the best name I could have found. `numberOfLikes` would have been more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have the user_id filled into your table posts and it's a foreign key, avoid to use a left join statement, you can get a better performance using join statement. To join 3 or more tables you can just add the join statement:
    SELECT 
        p.post_id
        , p.reply_to
        , p.parent_id
        , p.post_path
        , p.user_id
        , p.content
        , p.datetime
        , p.total_likes
        , p.total_replies
        , p.total_reposts
        , u.username
        , u.display_name 
    FROM posts p 
    JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.user_id WHERE p.user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM follows 
    JOIN TABLE_2 ON TABLE_2.id = posts.TABLE_id
    JOIN TABLE_3 ON TABLE_3.id = posts.TABLE_id
    ...
    WHERE 
        user_id = ?) 
        AND p.removed != 1 
    ORDER BY p.datetime DESC 
    LIMIT 26